# Google map in popup

Tags: asp.net

I m trying to display the google map in a pop up.
I m getting the "The TargetControlID of 'ModalPopupExtender' is not valid. A control with ID 'button1' could not be found." error.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
 <%@  Register TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         function load1(ModalId,map1) {

             var popup = $find(ModalId);
             popup.show();

         load();
         showAddress();
     }

      function load() {
         document.getElementById("map1").style.display = "block";

         if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
             var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
             map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
             map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());

             var center = new GLatLng(19.0759837, 72.8776559);
             map.setCenter(center, 11);
             map.setMapType(G_SATELLITE_MAP);
             geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();

             var marker = new GMarker(center, { draggable: true });
             map.addOverlay(marker);
             document.getElementById("TextBox5").value = center.lat();
             document.getElementById("TextBox6").value = center.lng();

             geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();

             GEvent.addListener(marker, "dragend", function () {
                 var point = marker.getPoint();
                 map.panTo(point);
                 document.getElementById("TextBox5").value = point.lat();
                 document.getElementById("TextBox6").value = point.lng();
             });

             GEvent.addListener(map, "moveend", function () {
                 map.clearOverlays();
                 var center = map.getCenter();
                 var marker = new GMarker(center, { draggable: true });
                 map.addOverlay(marker);
                 document.getElementById("TextBox5").value = center.lat();
                 document.getElementById("TextBox6").value = center.lng();

                 GEvent.addListener(marker, "dragend", function () {
                     var point = marker.getPoint();
                     map.panTo(point);
                     document.getElementById("TextBox5").value = point.lat();
                    document.getElementById("TextBox6").value=point.lng();  
                 });
             });
         }
     }

     function showAddress() {
         address = document.getElementById("TextBox4").value;
         var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
         map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
         map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
         if (geocoder) {
             geocoder.getLatLng(
address,
function (point) {
    if (!point) {
        alert(address + " city not found !");
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("TextBox5").value = point.lat();
        document.getElementById("TextBox6").value = point.lng();
        map.clearOverlays()
        map.setCenter(point, 14);
        var marker = new GMarker(point, { draggable: true });
        map.addOverlay(marker);
    GEvent.addListener(marker, "dragend", function () {
        var pt = marker.getPoint();
        map.panTo(pt);
        document.getElementById("TextBox5").value = pt.lat();
        document.getElementById("TextBox6").value = pt.lng();
    });

    GEvent.addListener(map, "moveend", function () {
        map.clearOverlays();
        var center = map.getCenter();
        var marker = new GMarker(center, { draggable: true });

        map.addOverlay(marker);
        document.getElementById("TextBox5").value = center.lat();
        document.getElementById("TextBox6").value = center.lng();

        GEvent.addListener(marker, "dragend", function () {
            var pt = marker.getPoint();
            map.panTo(pt);
            document.getElementById("TextBox5").value = pt.lat();
            document.getElementById("TextBox6").value = pt.lng();
        });


      });
    } 
}
);
             } 
         }
</script>
 <script language="JavaScript">
<!--
     var message = "";
     function clickIE() { if (document.all) { (message); return false; } }
     function clickNS(e) {
         if
(document.layers || (document.getElementById && !document.all)) {
             if (e.which == 2 || e.which == 3) { (message); return false; } 
         } 
     }
     if (document.layers)
     { document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN); document.onmousedown = clickNS; }
     else { document.onmouseup = clickNS; document.oncontextmenu = clickIE; }
     document.oncontextmenu = new Function("return false")
// -->
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" />
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        Name:
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        Address:<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        City:<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" style="margin-bottom: 0px"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        Pincode:<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" style="margin-bottom: 0px"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        Latitude:<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        Longitude:<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
     <asp:Button ID="button1" value="Show on Map" onclick="javascript:load1('ModalPopup','map1');" ></asp:Button>
       <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="button1"
          PopupControlID="map1" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" CancelControlID="CloseMapButton"
          DropShadow="false" BehaviorID="ModalPopup" PopupDragHandleControlID="mapHeader" />
    <div style="display:none;margin-top:100px;margin-left:100px;" id="map1" class="row" >

    <div align="center" id="map" style="width:600px; height: 400px;"> 
                </div>
    </div>
    </div>


        </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

I can't understand why it is giving the targetcontrolid cannot be found.
Thanks,

Comment: It is a minor error plz someone help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. I added a hidden field above the modal popup and gave the id of the hidden field as the targetcontrolID.
Thanks all for viewing.